# Using GoogleApiClient vs usual way with Http and JSON

Tags: android, google-maps, android-googleapiclient

I have a question about using GoogleApiClient. Is it necessary to use this Object or is it ok to use HttpUrlConnection and send requests as I did it many times? Now, I am also developing Android - app, where important to use Google Places API. But I create it like this: 
1) Create search query
2) Send search request via Http
3) Get response as JSON and parse it out

Can anybody explain what the pros ans cons of each method, and which one is better? Thank in advance)

Answer (score 1):

I think this video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=KBhOkfbbZLk) gives a good idea about what GoogleApiClient can offer. As a quick summary, if the service is easier or only available through google (maps, sign in with google account, cross app syncing, etc.) then you should use the Object. Remember, you can always use both GoogleApiClient AND your own HttpUrlConnection requests.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the link, I will see.I asked because I was thinking it is like old-fashioned styleto use own HttpUrlConnection